# Uniformization of abelian varieties in function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I'm wondering how uniformization of abelian varieties works in the function field world. I know that in many ways people like to think of Drinfeld modules/Shtuka's as analogues of function fields and that for those, we have the Tate uniformization theorem (Drinfeld "Elliptic modules" Section 57 I think). However I would be curious if there is an uniformization of "actual" abelian varieties in some sense.

Comment: That link does not work for me, I get a "403 Forbidden" error message.

Comment: @red_trumpet I added an alternate source